# Wrap http call into shared function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, types, rxjs

I have a rest-provider service that has all of my http calls. However, each function is reusing a lot of the same http code and it seems like I should be wrapping this into a shared function incase I want to change anything in it

As you can see the 2 functions are almost exactly the same with just the url changing. How do I refactor this code to not reuse the same code in all my functions?

```
getStepMenu(_params): Observable<StepMenu> {
    // Add params
    let params = new HttpParams();

    for (let key in _params) {
      if (_params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        params = params.set(key, _params[key]);
      }
    }
    
    return this.http
      .get<StepMenu>(this.env.API_URL + 'api/step_menu', { headers: this.headers, params: params })
      .pipe(
        retry(this.retries),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }


getStepInfo(_params): Observable<StepInfo> {
    // Add params
    let params = new HttpParams();

    for (let key in _params) {
      if (_params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        params = params.set(key, _params[key]);
      }
    }

    return this.http
      .get<StepInfo>(this.env.API_URL + 'api/step_info', { headers: this.headers, params: params })
      .pipe(
        retry(this.retries),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I see is the api path, you can just pass it as an method argument as follows:

```
  getStepMenu(_params): Observable<StepInfo> {
    return this.callStepApi('api/step_menu', _params)
  }
  
  getStepInfo(_params): Observable<StepInfo> {
    return this.callStepApi('api/step_info', _params);
  }

  callStepApi(path, _params): Observable<StepInfo> {
    // Add params
    let params = new HttpParams();
    let url = this.env.API_URL + path;

    for (let key in _params) {
      if (_params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        params = params.set(key, _params[key]);
      }
    }

    return this.http
        .get<StepInfo>(url, { headers: this.headers, params: params })
        .pipe(
            retry(this.retries),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
  }
```

You can invoke it the same way by subscribing to the obserables returned:

```
getStepInfo(params).subscribe();
getStepMenu(params).subscribe();
```

Comment: I don't think this works. The return in callStepApi isn't actually calling the api.

Comment: @user2570937 The api is only called once you subscribe to the observable. So you can do something like `getStepInfo(_params).subscribe()` or `getStepMenu(_params).subscribe()` for the api call to happen.

Comment: yes, I am doing that from the previous code. However it's still not calling the api

Comment: @user2570937, Do you see any errors in the console. There shouldn't be any difference actually.

Comment: its very strange. If I use this line, it works:

.get(this.env.API_URL + 'api/step_info', { headers: this.headers, params: params })

but this line doesn't

.get(this.env.API_URL + path, { headers: this.headers, params: params })

and if i console.log(path) directly before the http call it is showing it correct in the console.

Comment: @user2570937 what if you construct the url outside of the get, as updated in the answer?

Comment: I tried that as well, and it does not work.